# Finding if lat/lon point is on street

Tags: streets, service-recommendations

Are there any services to determine whether or not a give lat/lon point is on a street?

I am working on an app that uses user entered lat/lon points but it only really makes sense if its on a street.  I want to generate multiple points for testing but the points need to be on a street.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MapQuest Open (API)**

You can use the **granularity** and **confidence** levels to determine if your geocode is street based using Mapquest Open.

http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/geocodequality.html

Geocoding Examples:

http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/#response

Street values

> B1    STREET  The center of a single street block. House number ranges are
>   returned if available.
>
> B2    STREET  The center of a single street block, which is located
>   closest to the geographic center of all matching street blocks. No
>   house number range is returned.
>
> B3    STREET  The center of a single street block whose numbered range is
>   nearest to the input number. House number range is returned.

In most cases address geocodes do not location the precise building/rooftop but are based on road/street network.
So you are likely to get the location of the street for your response - especially using the open geocoding from OpenStreetMap that Mapquest Open caches weekly.

Note you do need to sign up for an API key.
There is no limitation on the number of requests on the Open version.

More info
http://open.mapquestapi.com/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Mapperz answer.Your question sounds like Geocoding.there are generally two types of geocoding are there: Geocding & Reverse Geocoding. the one you are looking is Geocoding . There are many services available for Geocoding .Even Google has an API to do Geocoding process: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ .When you use Google API you can more formatted address than other API's
Note: you can get only 2500 address geocoded/day on using Google gwocoding API.
                 other source include BIng,Yahoo etc .Bing API can get 40000 address geocoded/day .